# MicroSD (Secure Digital Storage Device) is not formattable, deletable or reusable

Tags: security, sd-card, format

My question detected as a similar question, and the similar answer is to throw your SD in the garbage! I want to update my question by asking, what happens **technically** when a microSD card happens to act like that? It is totally readable, but not changeable, either delectable or formattable. It turned to a stone slab with carved data on it.
I recently trying to format and reuse a microSD card, which turned to "Secure Digital Storage Device" by an android phone 7.1 version. The data on the card is available and totally accessible but every moment I want to delete a folder it is automatically recovered. Even when I used it on the desktop, **I did not insert it into the phone**. Every possible solution in links like below turned out to not work.
https://www.reneelab.com/secure-digital-storage-device.html

I used many ways to solve this issue, which provided with other websites, they all failed to work:
Diskpart
Format,
Use the Registry.
Please note that I don't want to use third-party software. please do not post solutions like that. I am curious how this card is so undeletable, I can use it for other purposes, and this discussion open for your explanation. but for now, I want a method to simply reuse my micro sd as an ordinary sd card
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSa2Y.jpg)

Comment: He's dead, jim.

Comment: Flash media including SD cards can go in to 'read-only mode' because of damage, and when that happens, they are, as @music2myear says, dead. Not just shagged out after a long squawk.

Comment: SD cards often go into a final sort of "protection mode" as they die. You can read data, but you cannot write. Deleting is too similar to writing, and so you cannot do that either. You card is likely dead, and simple needs to be replaced.